# overlay geotagged photo in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I want to create a Google map with user uploaded Geotagged photos that show up on my map.  I can easily create manipulate my map but I can't seem to find instruction on how to add these geotagged photos.

Here is an example of what I am try to accomplish:
http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=26.892794,-80.055909&spn=0.003875,0.004828&t=h&z=18&lci=lmc:panoramio

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience working with photos, but I don't think it should be really any different than placing a GMarker on the map at the appropriate coordinates of your photo, and then in the info window of the tag you would output your custom HTML which would include your photo.

Edit: Specific link leading to the GMarker class in the Google Maps API Reference: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a tile, then create a tile overlay.

```
var tilelayer = new GTileLayer(myCopyright);
tilelayer.getTileUrl = function() { return "../include/tile_crosshairs.png"; };
tilelayer.isPng = function() { return true;};
tilelayer.getOpacity = function() { return 1.0; }

var myTileLayer = new GTileLayerOverlay(tilelayer);
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
map.addOverlay(myTileLayer);
```

The [documentation is here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Tile_Overlays), with a [great sample map here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/tileoverlay-simple.html).

Comment: The example is not a photo, but it is an image, which is the important part.

Comment: this is more of what I am talking about: http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=26.892794,-80.055909&spn=0.003875,0.004828&t=h&z=18&lci=lmc:panoramio

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP (or another script) to create a KML or GeoRSS file (much like Flickr's KML and GeoRSS feeds) and have the Google Maps API function GGeoXML load the file as an overlay on the map. 
See Google's example code here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/geoxml-rss.html

That example is actually loading a live GeoRSS feed from Flickr.